# Can't mount network drive properly over Wi-Fi (cifs error -101)

Tags: mount, wifi, raspberry-pi, fstab

**NOTE: this is a repost from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427248/cant-mount-network-drive-properly-over-wi-fi because it was off-topic there**

I am trying to mount a network drive on Lubuntu 16.4 Raspberry Pi edition. I want to clarify, that I can mount it using the mount command. The issue is with mounting it on boot. I've already modified /etc/fstab. It works properly when over Ethernet.

However, when only the USB Wireless Adapter is installed the network drive fails to mount (error code -101).

I have a suspicion that this is caused by not having initialized the Wi-Fi Adapter before Lubuntu mounts the drives from fstab.

What Can I do?

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks for the tip, @Cagri!**

I've also took a look at [this](http://codingberg.com/linux/systemd_when_to_use_netdev_mount_option).

Adding _netdev,noauto,x-systemd.automount to my options for the network drive seems to have fixed the issue.

The only side effect is, that the network drive appears twice in file managers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found a very good solution using automount with systemd

It is explained here : https://ppfeufer.de/linux-on-demand-nfs-and-samba-cifs-connections-with-systemd-automount/

**Install required package**

```
sudo apt-get install samba cifs-utils nfs-common
```

**Create a Mount Point**

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/network/myshare
```

**Create a Credentials File**

```
sudo nano /etc/samba/credentials
```

with inside :

```
username=your_username
password=your_password
```

then

```
sudo chmod 600 /etc/samba/credentials
```

**Create the Systemd Unit Files**

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mnt-network-myshare.mount
```

**Example: CIFS**

```
[Unit]
Description = My Share mount
Requires = dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service
After = network-online.target
Wants = network-online.target
 
[Mount]
What = //example.server/myshare
Where = /mnt/network/myshare
Options = credentials=/etc/samba/credentials,vers=3.1.1,uid=your_username,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0655,dir_mode=0655,noperm
Type = cifs
TimeoutSec = 30
 
[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

**Example: NFS**

```
[Unit]
Description = My Share mount
Requires = dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service
After = network-online.target
Wants = network-online.target
 
[Mount]
What = example.server:/myshare
Where = /mnt/network/myshare
Options = defaults
Type = nfs
TimeoutSec = 30
 
[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

**Auto Mount**

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mnt-network-myshare.automount
```

with

```
[Unit]
Description = Automount for My Share
ConditionPathExists = /mnt/network/myshare
 
[Automount]
Where = /mnt/network/myshare
TimeoutIdleSec = 0
 
[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target



Test

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl start mnt-network-myshare.mount
sudo systemctl status mnt-network-myshare.mount
```

Output like this

```
 mnt-network-myshare.mount - My Share mount
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mnt-network-myshare.moun; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-04-29 10:10:03 CEST; 1min 1s ago
    Where: /mnt/network/myshare
     What: //example.server/myshare
  Process: 13005 ExecMount=/bin/mount //example.server/myshare /mnt/network/myshare -t cifs -o vers=3.1.1,credentials=/home/your_username/.mount-credentials/myshare,iocharset=utf8,rw,x-systemd.automount,uid=1000 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mnt-smb-sambashare.mount
 
Apr 29 10:10:03 your_pc systemd[1]: Mounting My Share mount...
Apr 29 10:10:03 your_pc systemd[1]: Mounted My Share mount.
```

You can test the automount too

```
sudo systemctl start mnt-network-myshare.automount
sudo systemctl status mnt-network-myshare.automount
```

**Enable your automount files to start at boot**

```
sudo systemctl enable mnt-network-myshare.automount
```